# When i call a function: Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode

Tags: truffle, truffle-contract, solidity-0.5.x, calldata

I work on Truffle. My contract is `A` and its function is `infoRep()`. `infoRep()` returns some data. Whenever i call the function in Truffle console the below error occurs:

```
Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode    at PromiEvent (C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\contract\lib\promievent.js:9:1)
```

I don't know what is the solution. Please guide me to solve the problem.

A:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;
contract A{
bytes[] info;
    function infoRep() public returns(string memory, string memory, string memory, string memory){
        info[0]="Alireza Kiakojouri";
        info[1]="500";
        info[2]="0098";
        info[3]="AUT";
           return(string(info[0]), string(info[1]), string(info[2]), string(info[3]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
bytes[] info;
```

To this:

```
bytes[4] info;
```

Or this:

```
info[0]="Alireza Kiakojouri";
info[1]="500";
info[2]="0098";
info[3]="AUT";
```

To this:

```
info.push("Alireza Kiakojouri");
info.push("500");
info.push("0098");
info.push("AUT");
```

**But not both!**

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the array evaluating by `info[<index>]`. When, one creates a dynamic array, he doesn't determine  its length. So, compiler can't understand how many elements that array has and doesn't create any elements  for that. However, when one use `info[<index>]` for accessing or evaluating, compiler sees that element doesn't exist and returns an exception. Such, You should create dynamic array's elements then access them. Using `.push` creates the elements and after that you can access them. So, you can create and evaluate elements of `bytes[] info` by `.push` then access them by `info[<index>]`.

So try it:

```
info.push("Alireza Kiakojouri");
info.push("500");
info.push("0098");
info.push("AUT");
```

Or try:

```
info= new bytes[](4);

info[0]="Alireza Kiakojouri";
info[1]="500";
info[2]="0098";
info[3]="AUT";
```

When one uses `info= new bytes[](4);` the compiler creates an 4-elements array with default values. So, you can evaluate each element immediately.